# Repairing A Corrupt .MOV

Tags: 16.04, video, data-recovery, mov

Is there a way to repair a corrupt .MOV file?

- I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
- The only solution I found in 30 minutes of searching was to install the restricted extras package.  This didn't provide a resolution.
- I am able to open other .MOV files on my computer.

This is a 17 minute video which originated on a digital video camera.  I expect something went wrong between the video camera USB "CUT" and "PASTE".  I say this because if the microSD card has an issue the video stops recording and effectively goes into a "fail safe" mode to what has been recorded isn't lost.

I am unable to undo the CUT / PASTE and try again.

**UPDATE**

I know what the root cause is now: When I filmed I didn't wait for the video camera to save the video to the memory card before I powered off the camera.  This corrupted the video.  This is a learning experience.

Comment: Are you saying you had a working file on the camera but the pasted copy on the PC is not playing? This would be an undelete problem (on the camera), not a file repair one.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**

I believe [Untrunc](https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc/) is the perfect tool to fix your broken video file.

The Untrunc package can

> restore a damaged (truncated) mp4, m4v, mov, 3gp video. Provided you
>   have a similar not broken video.

You can install the package following the Readme in the repository, either compile it yourself or use the Docker container method.

Then, you can use the command

```
./untrunc /path/to/working-video.m4v /path/to/broken-video.m4v
```

to fix your broken video.

> Then it should churn away and hopefully produce a playable file called `broken-video_fixed.m4v`.

**Method 2:**

The online server [Restore.Media](https://restore.media/) has a very similar capability.  You upload the broken video and another working video taken by the same device.
The website can generate a low resolution repaired video for preview without charge.  But you need to pay if you want to download the full repaired video.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Launch "VLC media player".
Go to "Media"
Select "Convert or Save"
Add "corrupt .mov file" to be fixed.
Press "Convert or Save"
Provide the file name for the destination file
Select the desired Codec from the profile list.
Press “Edit Selected Profile” button to check a specified profile settings
You can also select to add a new profile or delete any existing profile
Press "Start"
```

Or

```
Create a copy of the "corrupt .mov file"
Rename the copy of .mov file to .avi file
Launch the "VLC media player"
Select "Preferences"
Press "Input or Codecs"
Select "Always Fix next to Repair avi files"
Press "Save"
```

Comment: I just found these steps on the web.  It didn't work.  It looks like I am back to refilming.

Comment: untruc recovered 0.8G of video out of my 2.2G corrupted video (4K camera ran out of battery and I think the file was not properly closed). Better than losing everything.